# How do parsers handle generic type parameters?

Tags: c#, parsing, generics, programming-languages, recursive-descent

I'm writing a recursive decent parser for an imaginary programming language. It's a C-style language with common operators like ==, <, >, <=, and >=, and it also features generic functions (like those in C#).

In languages like C#, to call a generic function, you write:

```
someFunction<T>(x);
```

My question is, how does the parser differentiate the generic parameters from comparison operators (< and >).

From my perspective, the code above could have either of these two meanings:

- call 'someFunction' with a generic parameter 'T', and with a regular parameter 'x'
- evaluate the expression '(someFunction < T) > x', treating 'someFunction', 'T', and 'x' as regular variables

How would the parser know which interpretation is intended?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#grammar-ambiguities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're 100% correct that the generic function call syntax is ambiguous in many languages which include the feature.

Not all languages use an ambiguous syntax. In Java, there is no ambiguity because the type arguments are placed *before* the method name, and must be preceded by a `.`: `SomeClass.<ArgType>genericMethod()`. Other possibilities include using a different symbol for type brackets, such as `[]`,  `::<>` or `!`. (Scala, Rust and D respectively. Scala uses parentheses for array subscripts.)

But many languages do use the C++/C# syntax, which is ambiguous. Every language has its own disambiguation rule, and as far as I know there is no cross-language consensus on how to do it. In particular:

- C++ requires the compiler to figure out whether the function/method/class name is (or might be) templated. (ADL makes this a bit tricky, and in C++18 the rules changed to include a case where a non-templated function/method name might still be interpreted as though it were templated.)
- C# requires the compiler to find the end of the angle-bracketed template arguments, if possible, and then examine the next input token; if the next token is an open parenthesis or one of a set of tokens which can not syntactically follow a `>` (for example, a semicolon), then the template arguments are handled as such; if there is no matching `>` or the matching `>` is followed by something like `42`, then it is handled as a comparison.

As far as I can see, a recursive descent parser which used the C# definition would need to be able to backtrack. The C++ definition, on the other hand, requires that name resolution be interwoven into syntax analysis, which is a different ugliness.

You are, as far as I can see, free to come up with your own different solution. I do encourage you to fully and clearly document it if you expect other people to use your language. (I couldn't find such documentation for typescript, for example, which I don't use.) If I were designing a language with generics, I think I'd go for an unambiguous syntax. But that's just me.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: D uses `someFunction!T(x)` style syntax for the templates. I find this syntax quite nice, since it's unambiguous, and syntactically distinct from everything else in the language.

Comment: I also personally would go for an unambiguous syntax if I were designing a language. I'm not sure what the C++ people were thinking.

Comment: @Coffee: ok, just for you I added D's syntax. I don't really want to maintain a babelfish of generic/template syntaxes, but I'm prepared to count to three. :-) I guess the C++ gang was thinking that you can tell because the compiler knows whether a name identifies a template or not. (Because you already have to tell it in the case of dependent types.) But then it turned out that ADL -- another "interesting" feature -- means that there are cases where you can't know until you reach the arguments. I like «», but many keyboards don't have them :-(

Comment: didn't expect you to edit, just wanted to make note for future people. Yup, that makes sense regarding C++. I forgot how hard it is to parse C++ compared to other languages. Most languages like to stick to ASCII, just because everyone has an ASCII keyboard. I'm fine with whatever syntax as long as it's not too crazy honestly. I'd probably go with D's syntax if I were to make a new language though.